# Two conditions with a single expression (both options) with regex python

Tags: python, regex, string

I wrote an expression that extracts all Dec Weekday or Weekend followed by numeric values:
Here is the expression I created:

```
    consumption_we = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z]{3} Weekend \d{4}-\d{4}) ([\d,]+\.\d{3}) (\d\.\d{4}) (\$[\d,]+\.\d{2})')
    consumption_wd = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z]{3} Weekday \d{4}-\d{4}) ([\d,]+\.\d{3}) (\d\.\d{4}) (\$[\d,]+\.\d{2})')
```

It works but I don't want to replicate the same expression for `Weekend` and `Weekday`. I was wondering if I could use a single expression that could meet both conditions. I use `Weekend | Weekday` but still gives me only one of the options most likely the second option.

My raw data looks like below:

```
Dec Weekday 0000-0800 2,242.144    7.4600     $167.26
Dec Weekday 0800-2400 14,178.264   10.8500    $1,538.34
Dec Weekend 0000-0800 785.168      6.2400     $48.99
Dec Weekend 0800-2400 4,972.248    7.9300     $394.30 
Dec Weekday 0000-0800 121.300      7.4600     $9.05
Dec Weekday 0800-2400 767.045      10.8500    $83.22
Dec Weekend 0000-0800 42.478       6.2400     $2.65
Dec Weekend 0800-2400 268.999      7.9300     $21.33
```

Any help would be appreciated, please.

Comment: `(Weekend|Weekday)` will match both

Comment: try this: "[a-zA-Z]{3} (Weekend|Weekday) ".... continued with your expression. This is a good website to test ur regex: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thank you so much, @Marat. That was a simple solution. I did not use the curly bracket. It works now. Hooray! Regex is still something I'm learning, and this is the first progress I've made thus far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the expression that you shared, you are trying to get weekdays and weekends separately, but if you use `(weekend|weekdays)` as some have suggested above, you wont get separate data.

So to get that, you can do this:
`

```py
import re

s = """
Dec Weekday 0000-0800 2,242.144    7.4600     $167.26
Dec Weekday 0800-2400 14,178.264   10.8500    $1,538.34
Dec Weekend 0000-0800 785.168      6.2400     $48.99
Dec Weekend 0800-2400 4,972.248    7.9300     $394.30 
Dec Weekday 0000-0800 121.300      7.4600     $9.05
Dec Weekday 0800-2400 767.045      10.8500    $83.22
Dec Weekend 0000-0800 42.478       6.2400     $2.65
Dec Weekend 0800-2400 268.999      7.9300     $21.33
"""
days = ["Weekday", "Weekend"]

for day in days:
    pattern = r'([a-zA-Z]{3} ' + day +' \d{4}-\d{4}) ([\d,]+\.\d{3})\s+(\d+\.\d{4})\s+(\$[\d,]+\.\d{2})'
    print(f"Day: {day}", re. findall(pattern, s))
"""
Day: Weekday [('Dec Weekday 0000-0800', '2,242.144', '7.4600', '$167.26'), ('Dec Weekday 0800-2400', '14,178.264', '10.8500', '$1,538.34'), ('Dec Weekday 0000-0800', '121.300', '7.4600', '$9.05'), ('Dec Weekday 0800-2400', '767.045', '10.8500', '$83.22')]
Day: Weekend [('Dec Weekend 0000-0800', '785.168', '6.2400', '$48.99'), ('Dec Weekend 0800-2400', '4,972.248', '7.9300', '$394.30'), ('Dec Weekend 0000-0800', '42.478', '6.2400', '$2.65'), ('Dec Weekend 0800-2400', '268.999', '7.9300', '$21.33')]
"""
```

Comment: This is perfect but the goal is not to separate Weekend and Weekday but to get them both without rewriting the same expression for each condition.

Answer (score -1):

first of all, I don't think your current regex is working, as you didn't match the spaces between columns 4 and 5. Here is the screenshot from https://regex101.com/ to match everything. The regex is

`([a-zA-Z]{3} (Weekend|Weekday) \d{4}-\d{4}) ([\d,]+\.\d{3}).+(\d\.\d{4}).+(\$[\d,]+\.\d{2})`

Here is the link to the regex101 - https://regex101.com/r/o579bx/1

[image]

Comment: DId you know that you can simply share a regex101 page? on the left side click "save regex" and share the link.

Comment: Thanks, that is a good feature, I just know to generate code. I have updated the answer with the link.